# Need help to combine 2 Outlook email Excel attachments into a single workbook with 2 sheets, one for each attachment, using Power Automate

Tags: excel, sharepoint, power-automate

New to powerautomate and just cant seem to figure it out

I have been successful in saving the attachments separately in sharepoint. Just cannot seems to get the two files to create a new combined file that contains two worksheets.

Comment: First of all next time include some more info on what your flow is already doing like screenshots or a high-level overview. We are here to help not do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/combine-worksheets-into-single-workbook

And: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Merge-excel-files-to-one-file/td-p/518405

And: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xp8bp9Bw0p0

Heres an overview:

- Use the `'List rows present in a table'` action to read in the tables one action per file.
- Create a new Excel file which you will combine the sheets.
- Create a new worksheet in the new Excel file and add the data to it for each of the data you got from the previous step.
- Setup a recurring trigger like once per week

Please see the resources above for further guidance. Try this and let me know if it helps.